# How can you detect if a scroll box (html element) is scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Weird question, but I would like to know if there is a possible way of detecting if a select box with the multiple attribute is scrollable (i.e. enough elements in list to require the scrolling of the select box) via jQuery or javascript ?

Regards,

Mary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare the visible `height()` of the element to the `scrollHeight`, something like this:

```
if ($('#foo').height() < $('#foo').prop('scrollHeight')) {
  console.log('scrollable');
}
```

Working example:

```js
var $scroll = $('#scroll');

if ($scroll.height() < $scroll.prop('scrollHeight')) {
  console.log('Target element is scrollable');
}
```

```css
#scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Works just as I wanted.

Comment: Thank you, [used this trick in testing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29052650/771848), works perfectly.