# Expect an element to have a scroll

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar, protractor

In one of our internal angular applications, there is a license text box displayed. Since there is a lot of text inside, the license box, represented as a `div` element, has a scroll.

**Question:** How to test whether an element has a scroll or not in `protractor`?

Here is an HTML representation of the element:

```
<div class="login-disclaimer-text-canvas ng-binding" ng-bind-html="disclaimer">
Copyright © Company, 2015. All Rights Reserved.
...
</div>
```

where `login-disclaimer-text-canvas` has the following CSS styles defined:

```
.login-disclaimer-text-canvas {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #3E6372;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick (originally proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19979473/771848)) is to compare [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) property:

> The `height` CSS property specifies the **height of the content area of an
>   element**. The content area is inside the padding, border, and margin of
>   the element.

with [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight):

> The `Element.scrollHeight` read-only attribute is a **measurement of the
>   height of an element's content, including content not visible on the
>   screen due to overflow**. The `scrollHeight` value is equal to the minimum
>   `clientHeight` the element would require in order to fit all the content
>   in the viewpoint without using a vertical scrollbar. It includes the
>   element padding but not its margin.

If `scrollHeight` is greater than `height` - then an element has a scrollbar.

---

In `protractor` we need to compare the resolved promises of `getAttribute('height')` and `getAttribute('scrollHeight')`. Let's make a reusable function and resolve one of two promises via `then()` letting `expect()` to resolve the second:

```
function elementHasScroll(element) {
    element.getAttribute('height').then(function (height) {
        expect(element.getAttribute('scrollHeight')).toBeGreaterThan(height);
    });
};
```

where `toBeGreaterThan()` handy matcher is a part of [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) third-party.

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering this.  Very handy.