# Protractor.js test case for Horizontal Scrolling and vertical Scrolling in angular2

Tags: javascript, testing, angular, protractor

How to write a test case to identify whether a view has horizontal or vertical scrolling through Protactor for Angularjs2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *reusable jasmine matcher* we use to check if an element has a *vertical scroll* (reference: [Expect an element to have a scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052649/expect-an-element-to-have-a-scroll)) (cannot guarantee it will work in your or all of the cases, of course - it works for us though):

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveScroll: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(elm) {
                    return {
                        pass: protractor.promise.all([
                            elm.getSize(),
                            elm.getAttribute("scrollHeight")
                        ]).then(helpers.spread(function (size, scrollHeight) {
                            return scrollHeight >= size.height;
                        }))
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Usage sample:

```
expect(loginPage.license).toHaveScroll();
```

---

FYI, here is an another one - checking if there is a scroll on a page using `overflowX` and `overflowY` CSS properties:

```
toHaveScrollOnPage: function() {
    return {
        compare: function(elm, visibility) {
            return {
                pass: protractor.promise.all([
                    elm.getCssValue('overflowY'),
                    elm.getCssValue('overflowX')
                ]).then(helpers.spread(function (horz, vert) {
                    if (visibility) {
                        return horz.indexOf("visible") !== -1 || vert.indexOf("visible") !== -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        return horz.indexOf("visible") === -1 && vert.indexOf("visible")  === -1;
                    }
                }))
            };
        }
    };
},
```

Note that you don't have to wrap the logic into jasmine matchers - you can make a helper functions or use the logic in any suitable in your case way.