# Protractor - automate the testing of horizontal scrollbar movement present in data grid

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor to automate the UI test cases of our developed angularJS application.

In my application we have a data grid with 20 columns, but on a screen user can see the 7 columns with data with the help of horizontal scroll bar user see rest of the columns and their data.

How can i automate the identification of horizontal scroll bar and their movement from left to right(till end of the data grid)?

Comment: This might be somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052649/expect-an-element-to-have-a-scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i faced the same problem at the beginning when tried to automate the UI grid table.what i used is  `scrollLeft()` and `scrollRight()` jquery functions to scroll the table based on any pixel values.

```
 var viewport = $('.ui-grid-viewport');
 browser.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).scrollLeft(arguments[0].scrollLeft + 20)",viewport.getWebElement())
```